# Kerberos keyTab Authentication from Tomcat/Catalina Applet

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, kerberos, jcifs

I've come across a odd little conundrum in modifying an plugin to support Kerberos authentication.

When specifying the below program with a password and KRB5.conf (or ini), I can successfully authenticate a subject.

However when running the below program to authenticate natively, a keyTab works perfectly. The catch is that my program, say we call it `kerbAuth.jar` is called from *within* Tomcat.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import jcifs.Config;
import jcifs.smb.Kerb5Authenticator;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;

import com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule;


public class testKRB 
{
    private static String URL = "smb://192.168.101.141/Share/";
    private static String KDC = "192.168.101.2";
    private static String REALM = "REALM.NET";
    private static String KRB = "/opt/app/config/krb5.ini";
    private static String KEYTAB = null;
    private static String PRINCIPAL = "user@REALM.NET";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException 
    {
        Console console = System.console();
        KEYTAB = console.readLine("Enter keytab path:");

        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.capabilities",Kerb5Authenticator.CAPABILITIES);
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.flags2",Kerb5Authenticator.FLAGS2);
        Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.signingPreferred", "true");

        try 
        {

            Subject subject = new Subject();
            login(subject);

            // List SMB files as a test.
            System.out.println("Files:");

            SmbFile file = new SmbFile(URL, new Kerb5Authenticator(subject));
            SmbFile[] files = file.listFiles();
            for( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
                System.out.println( "-->" + files[i].getName() );
            }

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void login(Subject subject) throws LoginException
    {

        Map<String, Object> state = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        state.put("java.security.krb5.conf", KRB);

        Map<String, Object> option = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        option.put("debug", "true");
        option.put("debug", "true");
        option.put("principal", PRINCIPAL);
        option.put("useKeyTab", "true");
        option.put("keyTab", KEYTAB);
        option.put("refreshKrb5Config", "true");
        option.put("doNotPrompt", "true");
        option.put("storeKey", "true");


        Krb5LoginModule login = new Krb5LoginModule();
        login.initialize(subject, null, state, option);

        if(login.login())
        {
            login.commit();
        }
    }
```

The above solution works perfectly when called standalone.

When called from within Tomcat, the following error is present:

```
SEVERE: [Console] Error authenticating Subject: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.security.auth.AuthPermission modifyPrivateCredentials)
```

Running `subject.getPrincipals().toString()` *after* making the login commit, I retrieve the Principal `user@REALM.NET`.

Looking at the KRB5 debug log:

```
Debug is true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /opt/app/plugins/user.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is user@REALM.NET tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal's key obtained from keytab
Aquire TGT using AS Exchange
principal is user@REALM.NET
EncryptionKey: keyType=18 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000; ......
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.security.auth.AuthPermission modifyPrivateCredentials)
```

Which tells me I can read the keyTab just fine and that I can read the principal (which I assume to be a privateCredential, but correct me if I am wrong).

In an attempt to get around the AuthPermission error, I did two things.

1) Added AuthPermissions to my subject initialization:

```
state.put("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission", "doAs");
state.put("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission", "modifyPrincipals");
state.put("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission", "modifyPublicCredentials");
state.put("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission", "modifyPrivateCredentials");
```

2) Added these same permissions to the java.policy (in that Java space):

```
 grant codeBase "file:/opt/app/plugins/kerbAuth.jar"
 {
      permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs";
      permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPrincipals";
      permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPublicCredentials";
      permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPrivateCredentials";
 };
```

3) Also attemped to modify the manager.policy for Catalina:

```
grant codeBase "file:/opt/app/tomcat/lib/-"
{
     permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs";
     permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPrincipals";
     permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPublicCredentials";
     permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "modifyPrivateCredentials";
};
```

However Catalina/Tomcat already has `AllPermissions` allowed for plugins/applets.

It looks like the `storeKey` call is part of the culprit, but without that I have to set `isInitiator` to `true` to get a commit that executes (but doesn't actually communicate with Active Directory according to Wireshark), yet the TGT does not save.

What I am looking for is any extra steps I can take in debugging where I need my AuthPermissions to be set, whether it be for Tomcat or the like, or if this is a problem elsewhere that I am not considering in java or Tomcat.

Java Version: 1.6.0_31 (native to the application, not the system)